# Mirror two Sharepoint Librarys

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to sync / mirror two SharePoint librarys on two different sites?

So when a new document is added, modified or deleted, that the other library automatically updates this document?

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box options to sync two libraries. There are several workarounds.

A hack to use the same web part in two different sites:  http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/03/sharepoint-one-library-multiple-sites.html

Use the Search Web Part. This won't allow updates in both sites, just will let you see the content from a library in another web site in the same farm. By default it will not look like a library table view, but it can with some SharePoint Designer customization.

If both libraries are in the same Site Collection, then you can use the Content Query web part. Again, you will need to do some customization to make it look like a library table view.

For all of the above, the users in the second site will need permissions to the source site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this still work if the webparts are in different web applications?

Comment: Okay sorry i read that it will not work between two sitecollections...
Is there maybe a way to do so?

Comment: Using the Search web parts is the only one that works across everything in a farm.

Answer (score 0):

Try SharePointMigration tool - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

I use it for site to site and Network to SharePoint/OneDrive for business migrations.

Works flawlessly with detailed error logs